# I would like to put a table under the Appendix

Tags: tables, appendix

I would like to put a table under the Appendix. However, if you write as below, the table stays outside the Appendix as shown in the picture. Is there any way to solve this?

```
\newpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}
(comment)
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
df  & df     & df   & df  & df    \\ \hline
sdf & sf     & sdf  & sdf & sdf   \\ \hline
sdf & sdf    & sdf  & sdf & sdf   \\ \hline
sdf & sdfsdf & ssdf & sdf & sdfsd \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: do you not need to specify where you want your table placed? that is if you want it placed where you put it in the file you have to specify "h" in the square brackets after \begin{table}.